# advancing a date with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I often am pulling data then manually advancing the date with the mouse 1 day before I can cntrl D that new date down. Is there a way I can bring that date down 1 day with keys, then cntrl D? (would make this process SO much faster)

Comment: Which software do you use?

Comment: o sorry currently I am using (for work) excel 2013

Comment: Can you post some screenshots too? It's still difficult to understand your problem

Comment: Also please edit your question with relevant info, don't put it in a comment.